# Create and pass JSON object to User Control in Dreamweaver

Tags: dwt

I have the requirement to create the json object by reading the field value of component in Dreamweaver template  and then pass this object to user control.and based on this object,i need to create the form in asp.net.

Comment: just wanted to know what do you want to achieve here. because in your solution json would be mere a string, which you are passing to usercontrol, Also your question is broad, What is your problem, what did you try? while implementing this Solution, should be in the question.

Answer (score 3):

With DWT alone you can not do this. There are two options:

1. Preferable: Write a C# TBB -> Construct the JSON from the Component Fields in C# TBB -> Push the object on Stack -> Use this variable as a string on DWT and assign it to a ASP.NET server side variable
2. You can make use of DWT Extension where again you will get the flexibility of C# to construct the JSON from Component Fields, and instead of pushing it to stack, you can simply make a function call to get this value in DWT.